# AngularJS $http.get return error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, frontend

My first time with http request. I use Angular for it. Server works normal - it's public news API. I need to get JSON file by URL like "hostname.com/article/2014/06/10/123?api-key=1234567890".

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    //some code there
    $scope.load_article = function( patch ) {
        $http.get(patch + "?" + $scope.apikey)
            .success(function(response){
                result = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                $scope.article =  result;
            }).error(function(response) {
                $scope.article = "error "+ response.status;
        });
    };
}
```

But when i call load_article() tracer shows me that result:

```
Method: OPTIONS;
Status: 596 OK;
Type: text/xml;
```

and "error undefined" into $scope.article.

Where is my fault?

Upd:

```
$http.jsonp(patch + "?" + $scope.apikey).success(function(data)){...}
```

Will be better for get JSON file.

Comment: The Http 596 error code usually indicates that the api endpoint you are hitting does not exist. Are you sure you're using the correct api call?

Comment: @zszep when I copy patch with api-key directly to browser it shows me correct json file.

Comment: OK, then it might be a cross domain issue. If it's working via http but not XmlHttpRequest, you may try JSONP to get the data. All modern browsers restrict cross domain call via javascript.

Comment: @zszep if I change "$http.get(patch + "?" + $scope.apikey)" on the "$http.jsonp(patch + "?" + $scope.apikey)", there is no statmen after calling load_article()... No success, no errors. Looks like that func ignored.

Comment: JSONP usually requires you to send a callback function in your request (you should look up the documentation for the api). If you'd tell us what public news API you're using, someone might help.

Comment: @zszep You are right. Brilliant! I added "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK" and everything was working fine. Thank you! If you create answer, i mark it correct =)

Comment: `$http.get(patch + "?api-key=" + $scope.apikey)` ?

Comment: @czwek no, "api-key" string already been in $scope.apikey. Problem was in JSON CALLBACK param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP usually requires you to send a callback function in your request (you should look up the documentation for the api). If you'd tell us what public news API you're using, someone might help.